# How do I test for failure or get the error?

Tags: powershell

Two situations.  first is the previously discussed `Start-Process` process that I need to use due to -wait.
[Start-Process, Invoke-Command or?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68727495/start-process-invoke-command-or/68729370#68729370))

1. How do I get the error from this since a command window opens and runs.

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Gyb\gyb.exe' -ArgumentList @("--email $UserEmail", "--action backup", "--local-folder $GYBfolder", "--service-account") -Wait
        $filename = "C:\reports\" + $UserEmail.Split("@")[0] + "_Backup.csv"
```

2. How do I know if the email sent?

```
Send-MailMessage @MailArguments -to $PEmail -cc -Body $Body -Subject $mailSubject
```

Comment: I am reading <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55971649/how-to-check-whether-the-email-has-been-sent-with-powershell/55981412> for the email bit and I am not certain I get an error on ndr.

Comment: That depends pretty much on the `From` address you use with `Send-MailMessage`. If it's a valid address you would receive the NDR there.

Comment: is there a PS means to check for error and ndr and then toss an error with the `send-mail` ? @olaf

Comment: No. An NDR is AFAIK always an email. So you would need an email client or you need to check the inbox of the according mailbox.

Comment: If something happens in the protocol session, for example "unable to relay" it will be reflected as a typical exception in PowerShell.  If this is part of a larger script and not strictly an interactive thing (where you'd see the error, you may want to error handle with Try/Catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer these in reverse order.

---

**How do I know if the email sent?**

[`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) will throw an error if the mail server can't send the message. Beyond that, you're at the mercy of the network of servers ensuring email gets delivered to the appropriate mailbox.

If you *really* need to verify receipt, you could always request a delivery receipt, but
`Send-MailMessage` does not support this. You would need to use `System.Web.Mail` namespace to prepare and send the mail instead, which you can set the `DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnSuccess` option. However, heed the following warning from Microsoft:

> The `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet is obsolete. This cmdlet does not guarantee secure connections to SMTP servers. While there is no immediate replacement available in PowerShell, we recommend you do not use `Send-MailMessage`. For more information, see [Platform Compatibility note DE0005](https://aka.ms/SendMailMessage).

The linked additional information explains that `SmtpClient` is the component at fault, and other .NET libraries are recommended for sending emails instead.

A less reliable option would be to wait for a Non-Delivery Receipt in the inbox of the sending account to appear, but there is no guarantee how long it might take to receive one back. You could wait 5 mins before declaring success, but the NDR might not come back for 10.

---

**How do I get the error from this since I command opens and runs?**

If you mean you want to figure out why the [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1) bit failed, you have three options. IMO both `Start-Process` solutions aren't perfect in this regard but will get the job done, but the third solution gives you the most control.

1. Tell the process not to run in a new window, but you can't easily evaluate the output programmatically.

> `-NoNewWindow` cannot be used with `-Verb RunAs`

```
Start-Process -NoNewWindow ....
```

2. Redirect the output to a file then read it, but this isn't scalable:

```
Start-Process -RedirectStandardOutput stdout.txt ....

$stdout = Get-Content stdout.txt
```

3. Use the [`Process.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-5.0) method with the [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-5.0) class to launch the process. Most robust, but more complicated than using `Start-Process`:

```
# Create process start information. See documentation for property details
$pInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo -Property @{
  FileName = 'ping'
  Arguments = 'google.com'
  UseShellExecute = $false
  RedirectStandardOutput = $true
  CreateNoWindow = $true
}

# Start the process
$p = [System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($pInfo)

# Wait until process finishes
while( !$p.HasExited ) {
  Start-Sleep 10 # Number of seconds to sleep
}

# Get the standard output as a string
$output= $p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

4. If you can, use the call operator `&` to prefix your command and execute your program. It's much easier to use than `Start-Process` and unless you need to use one of the flags of `Start-Process` (like `-Wait` for GUI apps). The above section **3.** can be simplified if we use `&` instead:

```
$output = & ping google.com
```

This works because the call operator *does* directly invoke the process, and the process output is able to be redirected. I have not tested this but I believe in this case STDERR can be redirected to the variable by [redirecting your Error Stream to the Success Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615047/584676).

The caveat to using the `&` call operator is that you are stuck with how it works; there is no customizing the behavior. Fortunately, it should work for the majority of use cases.

---

If you're a keen observer you will notice that `Process.Start` returns the same `Process` type that `Start-Process -Passthru ....` returns. You may be asking yourself, "why can't we just use the convenient-to-use cmdlet to return the `Process` object and simply consume its `StandardOutput` property?

We need to ensure that `$pInfo` sets a few critical properties which you can't set with
`Start-Process`:

- `UseShellExecute = $false`

  - Tells .NET to *directly* execute the `FileName` instead of invoking via a shell (e.g.
    `cmd.exe /c FileName Arguments`)
  - Required to redirect the `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, or `STDIN` streams for the child process
- `RedirectStandardOutput = $true`

  - Redirects the program's `STDOUT` to the [`Stream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=net-5.0) read by the [`Process.StandardOutput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput?view=net-5.0) [`StreamReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-5.0)
  - There are equivalent properties to set for redirecting `STDERR` and `STDIN` as well, `RedirectStandardError` and `RedirectStandardInput` respectively. [`Process.StandardError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror?view=net-5.0) and [`Process.StandardInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-5.0) work similarly as well, noting that the latter is a [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter?view=net-5.0).

Since `Start-Process` doesn't let you provide a `ProcessStartInfo` argument, nor does it provide parameters to control either behavior, file redirection is the only option. Otherwise, the returned process object with `Start-Process -Passthru ....` *is* the same type. Trying to use the `Process.StandardOutput` `StreamReader` doesn't work in this case, because there is no redirected stream to read from.

Comment: If the process actually writes to `STDERR`, you will also want to set `RedirectStandardError = $true` and read it later the same way: `$p.StandardError.ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: Oops, I actually removed references to `STDERR` and thought I mentioned to use the "Error and In"-equivalent properties for `STDERR` and `STDIN` redirection, but I guess I forgot. Editing now.